# Python: Need help making a triangle with a for loop with reducing numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I am currently trying to make a triangle in Python 3  that would look similar to below:

```
        0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    
        0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7  
        0    1    2    3    4    5    6    
        0    1    2    3    4    5    
        0    1    2    3    4    
        0    1    2    3    
        0    1    2    
        0    1    
        0
```

The requirements for this set is that It needs to be in for-loop format. 
I ask that I could get some assistance in finding the solution also this is for python 3 therefore it would be most appreciated if the solution is in that version but 2.7 is fine if you know the solution but not python 3.

Sincerely, 
Austin

Comment: I am sorry, but to people to help you, you should have attempted the problem. Most people don't like to come up with a solution from the scratch.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about solving OP's Homework from the scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 >>> for x in range(9):
 ...     for y in range(9 -x):
 ...         print y,
 ...     print
 ...
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
 0 1 2 3 4 5
 0 1 2 3 4
 0 1 2 3
 0 1 2
 0 1
 0
 >>>
```

Comment: would the final print be x?

Comment: that is just to print new line

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution using Python 3 (mainly different in `print()`):

```
l = list( range( 9 ) )
l.reverse()
for i in l:
    for j in range( i + 1 ):
        print( j, end="" )
    print()
```

Hope this helps.